# Using private apex methods in a test?

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

I am a newbie in salesforce. I have a helper class which contains private methods. When i try to cal the methods they are not being called and my code is not getting covered. Please help me out.

**Trigger:**

```
public with sharing class EF_TriggerHelper
{    
public static void createHandler(Schema.sObjectType soType)
    {
        EF_ITrigger handler = getHandler(soType);

        if (handler == null){
            //Error
        }

        execute(handler);
    }

    private static EF_ITrigger getHandler(Schema.sObjectType soType)
    {
        if (soType == EF_Requested__c.sObjectType){
           return new EF_RequestedHandler();
        }              
        return null;
    }

    private static void execute(EF_ITrigger handler)
    {
      if (Trigger.isInsert){
                for (SObject so : Trigger.new){
                    handler.beforeInsert(so);
                }
            }
    }
}
```

**Test Class:**

```
@isTest
private class EF_TriggerHelper_Test 
{

    static testMethod void EF_ReqstdResTriggerHelper_Test()
    {

        EF_Request__c objEFReq = EF_DataFactory_Utility.createEFRequest();

        EF_Requested__c objEFReqstd = EF_DataFactory_Utility.createEFRequested(objEFReq.id); 

        Schema.sObjectType stype = objEFReqstd.getSObjectType();
        system.debug('stype:' +stype);

        EF_TriggerHelper.createHandler(stype);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You didn't add the code for the trigger.

Comment: The actual code for the trigger shouldn't be required to answer his/her question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to call private methods in a test, just add the [TestVisible](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_annotation_testvisible.htm) annotation to your method:

```
public class TestVisibleExample {
    // Private member variable
    @TestVisible private static Integer recordNumber = 1;

    // Private method
    @TestVisible private static void updateRecord(String name) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Did not know this... thanks for the share!

Comment: It is a recent addition to Apex. Came out in one of the last few releases.

Answer (score 2):

You have a method called `public static void createHandler(Schema.sObjectType soType)`.  This method calls your private methods.  Use this to call them.

Comment: You should interact with your code as much like it will in production as possible.  As @dphil recommends, calling your createHandler code is the best way to test your private methods, since that is how they get exercised in production.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly call the private method from the test case but you can do one thing.
You can create a public method in your trigger like

> public callPrivateMethod(){
>
> .....call your private methods() here....

}

And finally just call this callPrivateMethod() in test case.
Hope it helps.

Comment: He already has a method that calls his private methods.